# webpack loader options in require.context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using `require.context` to import all svg icons as react components like this

```
const req = require.context('@svgr/webpack!./library', true, /\.svg$/)
```

I want to be able to configure the loader like I could in my webpack config

```
{
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [{loader: '@svgr/webpack', options: {icon: true, svgo: true}}],
}
```

Is that possible in require.context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline):

> Options can be passed with a query parameter, e.g. ?key=value&foo=bar, or a JSON object, e.g. ?{"key":"value","foo":"bar"}.

Try this (not tested):

```js
const req = require.context('@svgr/webpack?icon&svgo!./library', true, /\.svg$/)
```